# how to change xeditable color while data change in angluarjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, x-editable, angular-xeditable

[image]i am using angular js for binding the data in table and i have a crud operation on that .my need is  when i change xeditable value change the  color of xeditable where value should be  changed
Here i attached my sample code and my refrence

```
   <td  ng-click="rowform.$show()" id="df">                     
   <span   editable-text="contacts.FirstName" e-name="name" e-form="rowform" onaftersave="Fclick(contacts._id,contacts.FirstName)">{{ contacts.FirstName || 'empty' }}
  </span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/78/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.editable-controls input, .editable-select select{
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
```

this should do the trick.
Here is a link to a working version

http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/18616/

Comment: hi @Brent Boden  its woks but i need only higlighting the edited values xeditable

Comment: Thanks @brent I want to change the cell color immediately , when the xeditable values are changed.

Comment: Yes like this but when mouseover means it's hide@brent thanks for ur effort

Comment: If this is the answer to your question please check of the answer ?